Sqlite database apparently not created on Azure host
I'm developping some sort of work related POC and didn't want to bother with hosting a database etc... so I turned to Sqlite. The application in itself is a very basic web application based on .Net Core 8.0 MVC.
Locally everything works fine, I can start my app, it creates a data.db file if its not present, auto applies migrations...
The troubles start after deploying on Azure. I'm using a basic ADO pipeline if that's relevant with flag deploymentMethod: runFromPackage.
When I try to start my app using the Azure console, I see all tables being created according to my migrations and then, after first attempt at inserting data :
Encountered error while starting the application, see the exception for more details
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory'.

Some information that will be relevant to my issue :

I'm using this connection string : "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=MyDb.db;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared" since if I'm not creating it in memory I get an error for my app is not allowed to create a new file.
My local connection string is : "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=Data/MyDb.db"
The error happens in my code when calling await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync(); (which is roughly the first time an insertion is performed)
I can see very clearly in the logs before it fails that the table seems to be correctly created :

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
  "MigrationId" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY,
  "ProductVersion" TEXT NOT NULL
);

(followed by many more table creations from EF Identity)
I tried changing the Azure connection string by removing the ;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared part but then I got the error (expected) that I don't have sufficient rights to create a file there (that's not exactly this message, but that's what it means).
I'd really like to avoid having to create a Sql Server database or any similar thing, this app is only used by me, it is very low workload and low usage.
Thanks in advance for your help and time.
